# Determining the Number of Lines in a Textbox in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a textbox set up in a GUI where the user can enter information. This string is then spit out in a textbox within a PPT slide. Depending on the number of lines used in the textbox within the PPT slide, I need to enter the next set of information so many new lines below the text from the textbox. Here is what I have so far:

This is the code that takes the text the user enters in the textbox within the GUI and places it in the textbox within the PPT slide:

```
Private Sub Location()

   With ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningData").TextFrame2
     'Make sure there is text in the call to action textbox. If not, display an error message.
     If C2AText = "" Then
       MsgBox "Woah there! You need to enter text in the location/call to action box."
     'Otherwise, if text is inserted, place that text in the WarningData box found on the PPT slide.
     Else
       .TextRange = C2AText
       .TextRange.Paragraphs.Font.Size = 21
       .TextRange.Paragraphs.Font.Name = "Calibri"
       .TextRange.Paragraphs.Font.Shadow.Visible = True
       .TextRange.Paragraphs.Font.Bold = msoTrue
     End If
   End With

End Sub
```

This text determines whether or not anything is selected in the HailInfo drop down. If it is, I need to place this text so many lines below the C2AText that was inserted in the previous Sub:

```
Private Sub HailInfo()
Call Dictionary.HailInfo

ComboBoxList = Array(CStr(HailDropDown))

   For Each Ky In ComboBoxList
   'On Error Resume Next
     With ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningData").TextFrame2
       'If nothing is selected in HailDropDown, do nothing and exit this sub.
       If HailDropDown = "" Then
         Exit Sub
       'If a hail option is selected, execute the following code.
       ElseIf HailDropDown <> "" And C2AText.LineCount = 2 Then
         .TextRange = .TextRange & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & dict2.Item(Ky)(0)
       ElseIf HailDropDown <> "" And C2AText.LineCount = 3 Then
         .TextRange = .TextRange & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & dict2.Item(Ky)(0)
       End If
     End With
   Next

   Set dict2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Using the C2AText.LineCount within the HailInfo sub does not appear to do anything. It will not insert the hail text anywhere, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated...thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following ...

```
Private Sub HailInfo()
Call Dictionary.HailInfo

ComboBoxList = Array(CStr(HailDropDown))

   For Each Ky In ComboBoxList
   'On Error Resume Next
     With ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningData").TextFrame2
       'If nothing is selected in HailDropDown, do nothing and exit this sub.
       If HailDropDown = "" Then
         Exit Sub
       'If a hail option is selected, execute the following code.
       Else
         .TextRange.Text = .TextRange.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & dict2.Item(Ky)(0)
       End If
     End With
   Next

   Set dict2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

You were only referencing `.TextRange`, rather than `.TextRange.Text`.

Also, because you need to add the text at the end, you only need an `Else` condition, rather than two `ElseIf`s that both do the same thing! ;0)

---

More example code ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822136.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but those two ElseIf statements are supposed to do two different things. They insert a different number of new lines (vbCrLF) based on how many lines of text are input in the C2AText by the user.

Comment: In the code you supplied, they both do exactly the same thing!

Comment: Oh! Good catch. There is actually a different number of vbCrLF's in each one.